# File google-services.json

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a problem.I want to install firebase

```
.Build.gradle(project) 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location: 
>     C:\Users\Yavuz\Desktop\Vize\DersZamani2\app\src\debug\google-services.json
>     C:\Users\Yavuz\Desktop\Vize\DersZamani2\app\google-services.json

Answer (score 0):

The docs have info. Follow the instructions for an Android app

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en#android

Answer (score 0):

When you configure your project on Firebase Console, you would have downloaded `google-services.json` file. If not, then go to your project in Firebase console and download it again.

Put `google-services.json` file in your project's `app` directory and sync `Gradle` again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

You have to add google-services.json in your app folder and add this in your project gradle:

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
```

Then, in your module Gradle file (usually the app/build.gradle), add the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin:

```
dependencies {
   // ...
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'

   // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
   // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
   }
  // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```